# algorithm - O(1) to check if mouse hovering one of array of circles

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, coordinates, rect

generally to check if `mouse move` event `x` and `y` is intercepting any polygon inside array of polygons is:

```
on mousemove (e)->
  for c in circles
     if intercept(e.x, e.y, c)
        ...
```

just wondering if i can check it without `for` loop, like:

```
on mousemove (e)->
  i = calidx(e.x, e.y)
  if intercept(e.x, e.y, circles[i])
```

seems every `mousemove` event loop through all array items is not efficient

is it possible to use O(1) complexity to find out which array item is hovering?

Comment: It needs to be `O(n)` unfortunately. In order to know if a circle is intersecting the point you will need to check each circle against that point. Unless the circles have a very strict placement that you know about.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek how about i add all pixels into an object, for example `800x600` produce a array with size 480000, each object with key like `163:345` where formatted as `x:y`, then only run O(n) once to bind circle coordination to the object, will it improve performance?

Comment: That will probably do more harm than good. It would be a very large object and cost lots of memory space. There are problems as the solution below points out.

Comment: Are the circles stationary or nearly stationary? If yes, you might modify the Quadtree algorithm to reduce the number of tests required with each mousemove. Quadtree works by skipping collision tests between objects that are too far apart to possibly be colliding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using lookup table makes it amortized O(1) (but painful to setup/update)**

One way to do it with *amortized O(1)* is using a table lookup. This means you'll need to store each pixel coordinate with the circle ID it belongs to like this:

> pixel(0,0) --> no circle
>
> pixel(0,1) --> circle#1
>
> pixel(0,2) --> circle#1,circle#2
>
> ...

So you can quickly lookup the table with a particular pixel coordinate and retrieve the circles it belongs to. This lookup can be done with amortized O(1).

**However, it's a pain in the ass to set the table up / or update it**

The algorithm to set the lookup table is painful, highly complex. You'll need to populate all pixel coordinates of each of the circles you have and make the complete table. This is highly complex and updating the new position of the existing circles is even worse. It takes some computation to update the lookup table.

The approach is affordable when:

- Your circles are static. After you setup circles, they won't move or get resized.
- You have a small canvas.

In contrast, this is evil and worse when:

- Your circles are dynamic. They keep moving, resizing, added or removed all the time. This costs the updating phase a grave overhead.
- You have a large canvas.

Comment: yea, i just think about this. but seems not a good solution since my canvas is resizable...

Comment: When the canvas / circles are dynamic, it's definitely need to be much more complex than O(1). All you can do is minimizing the complexity but it will never reach O(1).

Comment: is there any O(log(n)) solution on this?

Comment: I'm afraid the explicit calculation would need to be at least O(N). Let's say you have `n` circles. You may want to calculate the distance from pixel `(e.x,e.y)` to **the center of each circle**. If the distance is shorter or equal to the radius of any circles, so it lies within that circle. However, as you can see, it seeminly needs to be at least O(N).